# Interacting with custom CellFactory node adds row to TableView selection list?

Tags: javafx

I have a `TableView` with a `CellFactory` that places a `ComboBox` into one of the columns. The `TableView` has `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE` enabled but it is acting odd with the `ComboBox` cell.

When the users clicks on the `ComboBox` to select a value, that row is added to the list of selected rows. Instead, clicking on the `ComboBox` should either select that row and deselect all others (unless CTRL is being held), or it should not select the row at all, but only allow for interaction with the `ComboBox`.

I am not sure how to achieve this.

Here is a complete example to demonstrate the issue:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

enum Manufacturer {
    HP, DELL, LENOVO, ASUS, ACER;
}

public class TableViewSelectionIssue extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Simple TableView
        TableView<ComputerPart> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<ComputerPart, Manufacturer> colManufacturer = new TableColumn<>("Manufacturer");
        TableColumn<ComputerPart, String> colItem = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        colManufacturer.setCellValueFactory(t -> t.getValue().manufacturerProperty());
        colItem.setCellValueFactory(t -> t.getValue().itemNameProperty());

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colManufacturer, colItem);

        // CellFactory to display ComboBox in colManufacturer
        colManufacturer.setCellFactory(param -> new ManufacturerTableCell(colManufacturer, FXCollections.observableArrayList(Manufacturer.values())));

        // Add sample items
        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new ComputerPart("Keyboard"),
                new ComputerPart("Mouse"),
                new ComputerPart("Monitor"),
                new ComputerPart("Motherboard"),
                new ComputerPart("Hard Drive")
        );

        root.getChildren().add(tableView);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class ComputerPart {

    private final ObjectProperty<Manufacturer> manufacturer = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final StringProperty itemName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public ComputerPart(String itemName) {
        this.itemName.set(itemName);
    }

    public Manufacturer getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer.get();
    }

    public void setManufacturer(Manufacturer manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer.set(manufacturer);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Manufacturer> manufacturerProperty() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName.get();
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName.set(itemName);
    }

    public StringProperty itemNameProperty() {
        return itemName;
    }
}

class ManufacturerTableCell extends TableCell<ComputerPart, Manufacturer> {
    private final ComboBox<Manufacturer> cboStatus;

    ManufacturerTableCell(TableColumn<ComputerPart, Manufacturer> column, ObservableList<Manufacturer> items) {
        this.cboStatus = new ComboBox<>();
        this.cboStatus.setItems(items);
        this.cboStatus.setConverter(new StringConverter<Manufacturer>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Manufacturer object) {
                return object.name();
            }

            @Override
            public Manufacturer fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        });

        this.cboStatus.disableProperty().bind(column.editableProperty().not());
        this.cboStatus.setOnShowing(event -> {
            final TableView<ComputerPart> tableView = getTableView();
            tableView.getSelectionModel().select(getTableRow().getIndex());
            tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), column);
        });

        this.cboStatus.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (isEditing()) {
                commitEdit(newValue);
                column.getTableView().refresh();

            }
        });
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Manufacturer item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setText(null);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            this.cboStatus.setValue(item);
            this.setGraphic(this.cboStatus);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The example begins with a predictable UI:

[image: screenshot 1]

However, when interacting with the `ComboBox` in the *Manufacturer* column, the corresponding row is selected. This is expected for the first row, but it does not get deselected when interacting with another `ComboBox`.

[image: screenshot 2]

---

How can I prevent subsequent interactions with a `ComboBox` from **adding** to the selected rows? It should behave like any other click on a `TableRow`, should it not?

*I am using JDK 8u161.*

---

> **Note:** *I understand there is a* `ComboBoxTableCell` *class available, but I've not been able to find any examples of how to use one properly; that is irrelevant to my question, though, unless the* `ComboBoxTableCell` *behaves differently.*

Comment: Based on your image/code, am I correct in thinking you want the cells to be "always editing"?

Comment: @Slaw yes. I'd like to have the comboxes available for interaction at all times (without needing to double-click to begin editing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want an "always editing" cell, your implementation should behave more like `CheckBoxTableCell` than `ComboBoxTableCell`. The former bypasses the normal editing mechanism of the `TableView`. As a guess, I think it's your use of the normal editing mechanism that causes the selection issues—why exactly, I'm not sure.

Modifying your `ManufactureTableCell` to be more like `CheckBoxTableCell`, it'd look something like:

```
class ManufacturerTableCell extends TableCell<ComputerPart, Manufacturer> {
    private final ComboBox<Manufacturer> cboStatus;
    private final IntFunction<Property<Manufacturer>> extractor;

    private Property<Manufacturer> property;


    ManufacturerTableCell(IntFunction<Property<Manufacturer>> extractor, ObservableList<Manufacturer> items) {
        this.extractor = extractor;

        this.cboStatus = new ComboBox<>();
        this.cboStatus.setItems(items);
        // removed StringConverter for brevity (accidentally)
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        cboStatus.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.isShortcutDown()) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
            } else {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
            }
            event.consume();
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Manufacturer item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setText(null);
        clearProperty();
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            property = extractor.apply(getIndex());
            Bindings.bindBidirectional(cboStatus.valueProperty(), property);
            setGraphic(cboStatus);
        }
    }

    private void clearProperty() {
        setGraphic(null);
        if (property != null) {
            Bindings.unbindBidirectional(cboStatus.valueProperty(), property);
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd install it like so:

```
// note you could probably share the same ObservableList between all cells
colManufacturer.setCellFactory(param ->
    new ManufacturerTableCell(i -> tableView.getItems().get(i).manufacturerProperty(),
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(Manufacturer.values())));
```

As already mentioned, the above implementation bypasses the normal editing mechanism; it ties the value of the `ComboBox` directly to the model item's property. The implementation also adds a `MOUSE_PRESSED` handler to the `ComboBox` that selects the row (or cell if using cell selection) as appropriate. Unfortunately, I'm not quite understanding how to implement selection when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is down so only "Press" and "Shortcut+Press" is handled.

The above works how I believe you want it to, but I could only test it out using JavaFX 12.

Comment: This solution works quite well for my needs. I assume this could easily be adapted for other `CellFactory` implementations too, which is most helpful. Thank you.

Comment: There is an issue, however. After selecting a value from the `ComboBox`, it appears to be disabled until clicking off of that cell; only then can we click the same `ComboBox` again.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce that behavior in FX 12.